# Gaining the "I Believe I Can Fly" Achievement in Just Cause 2

Tags: achievements, just-cause-2

I can't find the best place to Base Jump in order to get the "I Believe I Can Fly" Achievement in Just Cause 2. Any of the mountains I scale widen too quickly in order to me to find a clear path that I can reliably control my descent while also achieving the 1 km drop I need in order to get the achievement.

I've tried it from the "highest point" of Panau Island (and I'm sure it's the highest point because I got the achievement for standing there), but I just wrecked into a tree and/or the ground frequently, because I can't get far enough away from the mountain-side. None of the landmarks I could find (Three Kings Hotel/Towers, Rocket Launch Pads) are high enough, and I am assuming that I cannot just do it from a plane nor helicopter. Though, admittedly, I haven't tried that yet.

Is there more than one place 1 km high that I can fall from in order to get the achievement? Should I be able to do it from any mountain tall enough provided that I control the skydive maneuvering well enough?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Mile High Club, which can be found in the top right corner of the map, is the most immediate option that comes to mind.  Confirmed by  Poindexter, thanks!

Comment: +1 I can confirm that you can get it from the top of one of the balloons of the mile high club.

Comment: ... that makes... so much sense. Huh. I'll do my best to get back to this tonight. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I wonder if you can just jump off of an airplane. I have the trophy but don't remember getting it. I do love this game, I'm going back and playing it again at the hardest level and doing 100% everything just because it's so fun to blow s**t up.

Comment: @Poindexter: And not from just jumping off the platform, it seems. Doh!